# How to access vm inside a vm via VNC?

Tags: virtualization, iptables, kvm-virtualization, vnc

For some reasons I installed virtual machines inside a virtual machine, like this:

A( B( C ))

where A is the physical machine, B is a vm and the network type is NAT. And C is also a virtual machine and the network type is bridged.

The OSes are Ubuntu 12.04 and the hypervisors are kvm.

I can access B via VNC and via ssh from A, but for C I can't use ssh because C has no IP address at the start. And I assume I can only access C via VNC.

I tried something like(on A):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $ip-of-A -p tcp --dport 6500 -j DNAT --to-destination $ip-of-B:5900
```

(I referred to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking#Redirecting_selected_ports_to_virtual_machines))

But it doesn't work. And I'm reading the man pages of iptables and hope someone could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have enough reputation to comment.

Assuming all Machines has single network adapter.
B is NAT and C is Bridged. You can access  B through  A.

Can C is accessed through B?

Can C is accessed through A?

If C can be accessed through B, you will have to forward a port from A to B and forward that port from B to port 5900 of C.

Assuming 65535 port of A is forwarded to 65535 port of B, 65535 port of B will be forwarded to 5900 port of C for VNC access. Same can be done for SSH and other services.

Comment: Sorry for reply so late. I think this problem can be solved through pre-configuring the IP address of KVM virtual machine. And I'm searching for how.